# If a series grows more slowly than any geometric series, can it ever converge to a rational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers

I was reading a [proof of $e$'s irrationality](http://www.mathshelper.co.uk/Proof%20That%20e%20Is%20Irrational.pdf) which, in some sense, uses the fact that the series $\sum \frac{1}{n!} = e$ grows slowly.

This got me thinking: can we generalize this and say "oh, $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$ has a inverse factorial rate of growth, that's too slow, hence it can't converge to a rational".

The closest in the rate-of-growth hierarchy I can think of are the geometric series, which do converge to rationals. So that was my guess of where do draw the line. Does there exist a function which a) grows more slowly than any geometric function, and b) converges to a rational number?

If there is one, is there such a function that grows as slow or slower than $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$?

Comment: Please edit your question to address the issues raised by mathguy and Simple Art in their answers.  I think what you're asking is this:  Can a sequence of nonzero rationals $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ sum to a rational number if $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}/a_n)=0$?  If so, I think it's a nice question.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Thanks for the suggestion! I definitely want nonzero and rational. Is it polite to repost this as a new question, after I clean it up?

Comment: @BarryCipra: Also, I think $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_{n+1}/a_n) = 0$ is too liberal, since it would allow $\frac{1}{2^n}$. I think I need "grows slower than any geometric sequence".

Comment: $(1/2^{n+1})/(1/2^n)\to1/2$, not $0$, so $1\over2^n$ is not allowed by the condition I suggested, which I think captures the essence of what it means to grow more slowly than any geometric sequence.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Ah, you're right! Thank you again, this is a very precise restatement of my question!

Answer (score 2):

The question makes no sense, really. Take any convergent series; take its limit $l$, and if the limit is not rational, add something just to the first term so the new limit is rational. (For example, add $-l$ to the first term to make the sum of the series equal to $0$.)

Did you mean something else, such as "all the terms are rational"? And perhaps also "strictly positive"?

Answer (score 0):

One could say that $\sum0=0$, it grows slower than both of your conditions and it is a rational number.

Also, $\sum\frac{[\ln(2)]^n}{n!}=2$, it is both a rational number, and it grows slower than a geometric sequence.

I'm not quite sure if I know any that grow slower than your factorial problem, but if it did, it could easily be tweaked to produce a rational number.