# If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 0$, can $\sum_0^\infty a_n$ be rational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a nonzero sequence of rationals

$$a_0, a_1 \dots a_n$$

"decays fast" in the sense that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1}/a_n = 0$, can the series converge to a rational number? That is, can $\sum_0^\infty a_n$ be rational?

The motivation is the idea that $e$ is irrational in some sense because its series $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$ grows too slowly. I was wondering if there was a way to make this precise.

(This is a restatement of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751809/if-a-series-grows-more-slowly-than-any-geometric-series-can-it-ever-converge-to?noredirect=1#comment3576371_1751809) question, with thanks to Barry Cipra!)

Comment: I may be oversimplifying, but what about an ordinary convergent geometric series?

Comment: @imranfat  The ratio is constant.

Comment: Incidentally, the "grows slowly" should apply to the series, not the sequence. The sequences decays *very fast* with this assumption.

Comment: @ClementC.: Thanks, you're right. Edited.

Comment: Well, I guess I was not understanding the "grows slowly" wording in the question then...

Comment: The fact that $e$ is irrational depends on the slow growth and also the fact that $nn!$ divides $(n+1)!$. There certainly exists an example of the sort you ask about. Not that I have one in my pocket...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about something like $.1, .011, .000111, .0000001111, \dots$?  Clearly the sum is $.11111... =  1/9$ and the $n$th term is on the order of $10^{-n}$ times the $(n-1)$st term.

Comment: That's it! Nice example.

Answer (score 3):

Second attempt at a solution:

Yes, example:

\begin{eqnarray} a_{n} = \frac{1}{(2)_{n}} - \frac{1}{n!} \end{eqnarray}
where the Pochhammer symbol is $(\beta)_{n} = \beta(\beta+1) \cdots (\beta+n-1)$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=0 \text{ and } \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} = -1. \end{eqnarray}